# What is the Power/Toughness of a */* when it is not on the battlefield?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If a creature has a P/T of *** / ***, but is not the battlefield, What is it's P/T with regards to effects that care about P/T such as [Wild Pair](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wild%20Pair) and [Varolz, the Scar-Striped](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Varolz%2C%20the%20Scar-Striped).

If I used [Varolz, the Scar-Striped](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Varolz%2C%20the%20Scar-Striped) to scavenge a [Boneyard Wurm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Boneyard%20Wurm), and I have X creatures in my graveyard, do I get 0 counters or do I get X counters?

Comment: You should accept Collin's answer. PS this also works with [Tarmagoyf](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=136142).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It depends on the card in question. If it can't be determined use 0.

> 208.2a The card may have a characteristic-defining ability that sets its power and/or toughness according to some stated condition. (See
> rule 604.3.) Such an ability is worded "[This creature's] [power or
> toughness] is equal to . . ." or "[This creature's] power and
> toughness are each equal to . . ." **This ability functions everywhere**,
> even outside the game. If the ability needs to use a number that can't
> be determined, including inside a calculation, use 0 instead of that
> number. Example: Lost Order of Jarkeld has power and toughness each
> equal to 1+*. It has the abilities "As Lost Order of Jarkeld enters
> the battlefield, choose an opponent" and "Lost Order of Jarkeld's
> power and toughness are each equal to 1 plus the number of creatures
> the chosen player controls." While Lost Order of Jarkeld isn't on the
> battlefield, there won't be a chosen player. Its power and toughness
> will each be equal to 1 plus 0, so it's 1/1.

When you scavenge [Boneyard Wurm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Boneyard%20Wurm) you will get a number of +1/+1 counters equal the number of creatures in your graveyard before Boneyard Wurm is exiled. (A ruling on [Varolz, the Scar-Striped](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Varolz%2C%20the%20Scar-Striped) reads: *The number of counters that a card’s scavenge ability puts on a creature is based on the card’s power as it last existed in the graveyard*.)